# Which is better between EigenObjectRecognizer vs. EigenFaceRecognizer

Tags: c#, emgucv, face-recognition

I'm working with Face Recognition project and I would like to know what is the difference between EigenFaceRecognizer and EigenObjectRecognizer and which is better to use.

Answer (score 8):

Technically there is no difference they perform Eigen PCA (Principle Component Analysis) and NN (Neural Network) classification. The EigenFaceRecognizer is the newer term coined by opencv as it's is generally used for face recognition.

Opencv have brought all 3 main face recognition algorithms under a single FaceRecognizer class and as seeing EigenObjectRecognizer under the class would breed confusion they renamed it to EigenFaceRecognizer. The FaceRecognizer class now encompass FisherFaceRecognizer, LBPHFaceRecognizer and EigenFaceRecognizer.

I'm not sure if Opencv left the EigenObjectRecognizer as a class for the EigenFaceRecognizer to inherit from but it is still accessible in EMGU. This is important as the Eigen classifier is a very clever method of performing PCA without putting your own NN or equivalent classifier to distinguish between the results.

This article will help you if your are using face recognition:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/261550/EMGU-Multiple-Face-Recognition-using-PCA-and-Paral

Cheers,

Chris